# Render a partial, but leave out a element in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I want to render a partial but not show my button for one page. My partial looks like this;

```
.reward
  %h4== #{number_to_currency(reward.price, precision:0)} Per Month
  %h5= test.test
  %h6 foo
  %p= foo.description
  %a.button.button-green{:href => foo(bar)} foo
```

And I call it like this

```
= render partial: 'foo', collection: bar.rewards
```

How can I render this partial without showing the button: This line:

```
%a.button.button-green{:href => foo(bar)} foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass another variable with your partial-rendering.

Partial:

```
.reward
  %h4== #{number_to_currency(reward.price, precision:0)} Per Month
  %h5= artist.number_of_supporters
  %h6 Supporters
  %p= reward.description
  - unless nopledge
    %a.button.button-green{:href => new_reward_pledge_path(reward)} Pledge
```

Rendering it:

```
= render partial: 'reward', collection: artist.rewards, nopledge: true
```

For those of you who *don't* know how this works, it's fairly simple: when you render a partial in Rails (ERb, HAML, anything) you can pass along variables for the partial to use. So using `render 'reward', collection: artist.rewards` will give the "reward" partial access access to the `artist.rewards` variable, but it'll be referenced in your partial as `collection`. So you're able to do things like the code above does.

Comment: Thanks that make sense. But I am still having a problem and am getting this error: `undefined local variable or method 'nopledge'`  For some reason the variable ins't being created, my render looks like this: `= render partial: 'reward', collection: artist.rewards, pledge: true`

Comment: If you're using `pledge` as your variable then the code won't work, at least not with what I provided---the element is only removed if `nopledge` is true. That means you don't have to pass it every time, just when you don't want to show it. Use `unless` and make sure the variable you pass is `nopledge` -- *not* `pledge`. Just to clear up any misconceptions you might have, `no` doesn't do anything special when prefixed to a variable.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I'm now calling it like this: `= render partial: 'reward', collection: artist.rewards, nopledge: true` and in the partial: `- unless nopledge`  and the error: `undefined local variable or method 'nopledge'`

Comment: Huh. I'll fire up a quick new rails app and see what works. Sorry.

Comment: That's kind of an odd bug. It works for me when I omit the `partial: 'reward'` and replace it with `render 'reward'`; not sure what is causing this but that should be left to another question. Using `render 'reward', nopledge: true` will work---but not `render partial: 'reward', nopledge: true`.

Comment: @TuxedoTomson you need to pass `locals: {nopledge: true}`